# PHP class or library to allow tweeting from a website

Tags: php, twitter

I know there are quite a few libraries out there that that allow Twitter to be integrated into a website. But I haven't yet found what I am looking for (or maybe my understanding of twitter API is lacking). I want to be able to tweet events that occur on my website - BUT in addition, I want to be able to add tweeted from www.example.

For instance, when I send tweets from my blackberry or iphone (or indeed from some other sites), underneath the tweet, there is a message that says, tweeted from (for example blackberry). Does anyone know of a PHP library or class that allows me to send tweets but also with a kind of 'signature' that says where the tweet was sent from?

**Edit**

Additionally, I want users to be able to tweet from my website. When they tweet, I would like the tweet to say that where it came from (for example, like it does for blackberry phones etc, as I described above).

It is not clear to me whether I still need a PHP application for this requirement, and also how to implement it. Do I need an additional library for allowing users to tweet from my website?

Note: my users do not log into my website using a twitter login, so my website does not have access to a users Twitter username/password etc.

Comment: I think you'll need a Twitter API key (authorized application)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must register an app at http://twitter.com/apps, then you can use this twitter class -> http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter_oauth

I wrote a tutorial on how to do this http://blog.cmstutorials.org/reviews/general/how-to-update-your-twitter-status-using-php , just follow the steps and you should be good to go

**edit: how to include a link**

you can write function to get a shortened url because you only have 140 charachters
you can then use this function:

```
function getBitlyUrl($url)
  {
                $bitlylogin = 'your login name';
                $bitlyapikey= 'your api key';
                $bitlyurl = file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&longUrl=".$url."&login=".$bitlylogin."&apiKey=".$bitlyapikey);
                $bitlycontent = json_decode($bitlyurl,true);
                $bitlyerror = $bitlycontent["errorCode"];
                if ($bitlyerror == 0) {
                $bitlyurl = $bitlycontent["results"][$url]["shortUrl"];
                }
                else $bitlyurl = "error";
                return $bitlyurl;
  }
```

then just call it like this:

```
$url = getBitlyUrl('yourlink');
```

you can then just add `$url` to your tweet

Comment: @krike: Thanks for the link and especially, your tutorial. One quick question: Can I include url links in a tweet?

Comment: yes but best way is to shorten it first using for example bit.ly services because you only have 140 characters

Comment: @krike: Thanks for the quick response. Looking good so far. Last thing I need to consider is if your nice class allows users from my website to send their own tweets. In this case, I want their tweet to indicate where it came from - i.e. the website (like it does for iphone,blackberry etc). Please see my edited question.

Comment: oh euh .. I'm not sure, I never looked for it. you will have to get a look at the documentation http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter_oauth/docs

Comment: @krike: nvm. Your class + notes is a great starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an application in twitter. And tweet via that application (using API) on twitter. the 'via XYZ' will be automatically added.

http://www.twitter.com/apps

Comment: What about accessing public HTTP interface?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an application at http://dev.twitter.com

(There you can also set information for "tweeted by" or your page url)

Afterwards you can use a library from the list here:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

like https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth or https://github.com/basilbthoppil/oauth_twitter
(It has to support the oauth authentication system I think some of the librarys on the twitter page are outdated)

When you create an instance of the library in your php script you have to pass your authentication tokens to the constructor (how you do this varies from library to library so just read the docs).

Any tweet posted by using the library will contain your "tweeted by" etc. information.