# Twitter Connect & Sending a tweet via PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I need to send a tweet via PHP, but they need to authorize my app & login beforehand. How can I utilize Twitter connect to do this?

Comment: What can't you find in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward guide here: http://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 0):

this question was already answered a couple of times:

[PHP class or library to allow tweeting from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416940/php-class-or-library-to-allow-tweeting-from-a-website/5417141#5417141)